# Configure h2 for spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I'm trying to configure spring boot to set my test datasource to use h2 in postgresql mode.
I set these lines in my test/resources/application:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db1;MODE=PostgreSQL
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

But spring boot keep loading me default h2 configuration.

How can I force spring boot to use my special h2 configuration ?

Comment: Is the file really `test/resources/application`? It should be `src/test/resources/application.properties`

Comment: The above configuration works out of the box. What issues are you facing?

Answer (score 2):

just do it in java-configuration like this:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Profile({ "dev", "demo" })
public class EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DriverManagerDataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:mylivedata;IGNORECASE=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1");
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }
}
```